# Spring MVC - request syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to talk to this request handler (sorry about the bad language, I'm brand new to spring, I think that's what it's called).  I've looked around and seen recommendations to set the logging level to `DEBUG`, I talked to our lead about it he asked that I not spend time with that.  I'm running out of ideas, I've googled around and looked at a whole lot of stack overflows and can't seem to find my way.

Here's my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/project/save", "/project/add", "/project/edit"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveProject(@ModelAttribute ProjectForm form) {
    ModelAndView mav = this.createBaseModelAndView("project/start");
    ModelAndView redirect = new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/projects");
    return this.projectUtils.saveProject(form, mav, redirect);
}
```

Sending these vars in the request:

```
projectId:          51c4619c036492494eca2740
vendorId:           5113babc0364a6e3eb6aa368
name:               Cedar Goodies
description:        ldfkj
url:                http://caseywise.com
openDate:           06/22/2013 12:00 AM
closeDate:          06/26/2013 12:00 AM
organizerId:        517da4b92e3a896d9c613b2e
allowIndividualShipping:    false
allowIndividualPayments:    false
allowOrderEditing:          false
items[0]:           51c461a9036492494eca2741
```

And these request headers

```
Accept:     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:    gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Connection:     keep-alive
Content-Length: 366
Content-Type:   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:     JSESSIONID=6eebd82250b5429bfd8bb5f82e42
Host:       localhost:8080
Origin:     http://localhost:8080
Pragma:     no-cache
Referer:        http://localhost:8080/admin/project/start
User-Agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
```

the ProjectForm object (from the saveProject method in the controller) wants these properties

```
private String projectId;
private String name;
private String description;
private Date openDate;
private Date closeDate;
private String organizerId;
private List<String> items; // hidden inputs for form submission, since we can't send an object through a form
private String url;
private boolean allowOrderEditing;
private boolean allowIndividualPayments;
private boolean allowIndividualShipping;
private String vendorId;
```

I'm getting back a 400 - `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()`.  Do you see any glaring errors?  Do you want to see more code?  Any ideas?

---

## EDIT

*Including the `ProjectForm` object per Pavel's comment:*

---

```
package com.ordercollector.viewmodels.project;

import com.ordercollector.controllers.utils.ControllerUtils;
import com.ordercollector.entities.ProjectItem;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateParseException;
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author jables
 */
public class ProjectForm {
    private String projectId;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Date openDate;
    private Date closeDate;
    private String organizerId;
    private List<String> items; // hidden inputs for form submission, since we can't send an object through a form
    private String url;
    private boolean allowOrderEditing;
    private boolean allowIndividualPayments;
    private boolean allowIndividualShipping;
    private String vendorId;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description the description to set
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return the openDate
     */
    public Date getOpenDate() {
        return openDate;
    }

    public String getOpenDateFormatted() {
        return ProjectForm.formatDateAsString(openDate);
    }
    
    /**
     * @param openDate the openDate to set
     */
    public void setOpenDate(Date openDate) {
        this.openDate = openDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the closeDate
     */
    public Date getCloseDate() {
        return closeDate;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the project's close date in a formatted string.  If the close
     * date has not been set, an empty string is returned.
     * @return String
     */
    public String getCloseDateFormatted() {
        return ProjectForm.formatDateAsString(closeDate);
    }

    /**
     * @param closeDate the closeDate to set
     */
    public void setCloseDate(Date closeDate) {
        this.closeDate = closeDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the organizerId
     */
    public String getOrganizerId() {
        return organizerId;
    }

    /**
     * @param organizerId the organizerId to set
     */
    public void setOrganizerId(String organizerId) {
        this.organizerId = organizerId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the item
     */
    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * @param item the item to set
     */
    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    /**
     * @return the url
     */
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * @param url the url to set
     */
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    /**
     * @return the projectId
     */
    public String getProjectId() {
        return projectId;
    }

    /**
     * @param projectId the projectId to set
     */
    public void setProjectId(String projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the allowOrderEditing
     */
    public boolean getAllowOrderEditing() {
        return allowOrderEditing;
    }

    /**
     * @param allowOrderEditing the allowOrderEditing to set
     */
    public void setAllowOrderEditing(boolean allowOrderEditing) {
        this.allowOrderEditing = allowOrderEditing;
    }

    /**
     * @return the allowIndividualPayments
     */
    public boolean getAllowIndividualPayments() {
        return allowIndividualPayments;
    }

    /**
     * @param allowIndividualPayments the allowIndividualPayments to set
     */
    public void setAllowIndividualPayments(boolean allowIndividualPayments) {
        this.allowIndividualPayments = allowIndividualPayments;
    }

    /**
     * @return the allowIndividualShipping
     */
    public boolean getAllowIndividualShipping() {
        return allowIndividualShipping;
    }

    /**
     * @param allowIndividualShipping the allowIndividualShipping to set
     */
    public void setAllowIndividualShipping(boolean allowIndividualShipping) {
        this.allowIndividualShipping = allowIndividualShipping;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the given date in the format used by the form.  If date object
     * is null, an empty string is returned.
     * @param date
     * @return String
     */
    public static String formatDateAsString(Date date) {
        if (null == date) 
        {
            return new String("");
        } 
        else 
        {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a");
            return df.format(date);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the vendorId
     */
    public String getVendorId() {
        return vendorId;
    }

    /**
     * @param vendorId the vendorId to set
     */
    public void setVendorId(String vendorId) {
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try changing the signature of `saveProject` to have just a single `@RequestParam` argument just to see if that will cause the request to get mapped there.

Comment: what is your client? HTML/JSP page or standalone rest client ??

Comment: Try to remove items[0]: 51c461a9036492494eca2741, just to check. Usually, Lists causes problems on spring mvc

Comment: @RaviKhakhkhar I'm making use of a JSP to collect the data and pass it along in the ajax request.

Comment: Set your log level to debug and inspect it. Spring is most probably logging the problem.

Comment: @Renanlf "usually"? I've never had any problem with collections. However I spot dates... people usually do not realize how date conversion works. @Fusion please post the `ProjectForm` bean and make sure you are using `@DateTimeFormat` annotations.

Comment: @Renanlf, thanks for the suggestion of the `list[]` items, tried it but that didn't appear to work.  Thank you for looking and offering up your suggestion.

Comment: @PavelHoral edited question, included `ProjectForm` class.

Answer (score 3):

Spring by default (from version 3) is using `DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory` for `Date` field binding.

Your `Date` fields or getters in your model object must be annotated with the correct `@DateTimeFormat` annotation:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")
public Date getCloseDate() {
    return closeDate;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the note.  I didn't know about using annotations for date field bindings, very neat!  Gonna see if this works right now.